# CSS3: nth-of-type не работает

Tags: css3, nth-of-type

```
<div class="sizes1">
    <div class="size-item">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        4
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .sizes1 .more-features1:nth-of-type(1) {
        background: green;
    }
</style>
```

Нужно закрасить блок с контентом 2. В родительском блоке с классом `sizes1` ищу первый блок с классом `more-features1` и пытаюсь его закрасить. Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD**
То, что Вам надо, на чистом css без "костлей" не сделать. Можно, конечно, придумать такую конструкцию - сначала закрашиваем все элементы с классом .more-features1, а затем для тех, которые идут после первого, отменяем закрашивание.

```css
.more-features1 {
  background: green;
}
.more-features1 ~ .more-features1 {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes1">
    <div class="size-item">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Но по мне так это не очень. Уж лучше тогда js использовать:

```
document.querySelector(.more-features1)
```

Такой код выберет первый элемент с соответствующим классом.

---

Потому что элемент идёт не первым, а вторым - в таком случае надо писать :nth-of-type(2)

```css
.sizes1 .more-features1:nth-of-type(2) {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="sizes1">
    <div class="size-item">
        1
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Я не знаю какой элемент по счету. Поэтому нужно выбрать первый с соответствующим классом.

Comment: @ИгорьБаранюк, я обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

Логика CSS тут такая:
Переставьте, что вы ищете селектором конструкцию у которой есть 2 класса `class1` и `class2`.

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

Селектор при этому будет такой `.class1.class2 {}`.

В вашем случае есть селектор класса `.more-fearutes1`, а вместо второго селектора класса у вас селектор типа `:nth-of-type(1)`. Элемент будет выбран селектором `.more-features1:nth-of-type(1)` только если они оба соответствуют элементу одновременно. Очевидно таких элементов нет, т.к. элементы с классом `more-features1` является 2, 3 и 4 по типу.

Answer (score 0):

Еще один костыль, кажется работает. Тип елемента сменил где класса нет

```
<div class="sizes1">
    <span class="size-item">
        1
    </span>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        2
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        3
    </div>
    <div class="more-features1 size-item">
        4
    </div>
</div>
```